# CSS - vertically center an image within a floated div

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

I've decided to throw in the towel on this problem and need some help :).  As per title trying to vertically align an image wrapped in an anchor element in the center of a floated fixed height div.

Done a lot of googling for solutions and the closet I can get is below when the div is not floated (however it needs to be).  Any ideas would be greatfully appreciated!

```
.class_name {
/*float: left*/
width:153px; 
height:153px;
margin:3px;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #dedede;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #000;
display: table-cell;
}

<div class="class_name">
    <a href=""><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

Well, I bumped into the same issue last night (for a gallery-like type of thing), and managed to find a solution after stumbling onto [this page](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html). I'm happy to report this also seems to work for floated elements!

The trick is basically to give the outer element "display: table;", and the inner element (containing the img) "display: table-cell;".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
.class_name {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 153px; 
    height: 153px;
}

.class_name a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="class_name">
         <a href=""><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For IE8, you do need to be in standards mode. Some additional positioning is needed to get it to work in IE7:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]><style type="text/css">
.class_name {
    position: relative;
}
.class_name a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
.class_name img {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style><![endif]-->
```

Comment: neat. Don't know if it's the best way but works nice http://www.jsfiddle.net/NgqE2/

Comment: Remember to put the image inside some other tag. It was `<a>` in this case. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the height is fixed and you know the size of the image, just position the image manually. Use `position:absolute;top:25px;` on the image or something like that, or add a margin to the image: `margin:25px 0;`.

Comment: Unfortunately the image can be a different height sometimes.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There is a cross browser css solution for this available here: http://www.vdotmedia.com/blog/vertically-center-content-with-css/

Comment: Ah yes I came across this.  Still same issue though when it's floated which very frustrating!